# Scala: Initialize Object with External Parameters

Tags: scala, object, constructor

Assume I have a variable `x` which receives its value from the user at some point. Once that is done, I need to set up an Object which needs the value of `x`.

Naively, I'd like to write:

```
Object MyCoolObject(num:Double) {
  //code
}
```

and then somewhere in the code:

```
val MCO = MyCoolObject(x)
```

But that's not possible in Scala. So how do I do it?

Comment: I think you will need to dig around companion object and apply method.

Comment: It looks like everyone here is pretty confused about this question - maybe you should back up a bit and explain at a higher lever what you're trying to accomplish, and give some additional context? Otherwise I think the answer to the exact question you've presented so far is simply that it isn't possible to parameterize an `object`.

Answer (score 1):

This is already discussed here: [Pass Parameters to Scala Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457278/pass-parameters-to-scala-object)

You can also use a `case class`:

```
  case class MyCoolObject(num: Double)
  {
    //code
  }


  val n = 10 // external data
  val myCoolObject = MyCoolObject(n)
```

Comment: Thanks, but not what I'm looking for - I need to keep it as an object and not a class. also, the MongoDB way to do so is not what I have here. It's really is about passing a parameter, like `n` in your example

Comment: You have some misunderstanding of how Scala objects are created. Please read the duplicate question link I shared.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
class MyCoolObject(num:Double) {    
}

object MyCoolObject{
    def apply(x:Double) = new MyCoolObject(x)
}

val x : Double = 56.1
val MCO = MyCoolObject(x)
```

You can use this article i.e.
https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/basics2.html

Comment: How do I call it? `val MCO = Bar(x)`? Will `MCO` hold the object or the class?

Comment: Just amended answer with proper code for you need. MCO will hold new instance of the class.

Comment: Is there any way to this with `MCO` still being an object and not an instance of a class?

Comment: Well, I would say yes. Not sure why you need this. But I would do something like:                                                                                                            object MyCoolObject{
  var myValue : Double = 0

  def apply(x: Double) = {   
   myValue = x 
   this
  }
 }

Comment: You will store you value in the companion object. Try do println ( MCO.myValue) .